# Get rows with same date and month for each year

Tags: r

I have a large dataset and I want to pick out some of the rows particularly, I am wondering if anyone could help me with this? Thank you so much for your help!!

For example, if I just want pick out rows with the same day and month for each year in the df. In my df I got every day from 01/01/2010 to 01/01/2021. Let's say I want the 2nd of May for each year, how can I do that? My aim is to do that for every day (maybe there is a function or a simple way to do that?). Thank you very much for your help!!

```
df<- data.frame(Date = c("05-02-2010","07-06-2011","05-02-2011", "07-03-2020", "05-02-2018"),
            Name = c("Alexander", "John", "Alexander", "James", "Chris"))
```

The result should be like that:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert to date object and then you can `filter` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

result <- df %>%
  mutate(Date = mdy(Date)) %>%
  filter(month(Date) == 5 & day(Date) == 2)
```

In base R -

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, '%m-%d-%Y')
result <- subset(df, format(Date, '%m-%d') == '05-02')

#        Date      Name
#1 2010-05-02 Alexander
#3 2011-05-02 Alexander
#5 2018-05-02     Chris
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast help!!! It seems to work :D

Answer (score 1):

We could just use `substr`

```
subset(df, substr(Date, 1, 5) == '05-02')
        Date      Name
1 05-02-2010 Alexander
3 05-02-2011 Alexander
5 05-02-2018     Chris
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note, the dataframe you've created is made of character dates. They are not dates

Two possible solutions:

as stated above, the date column is not in Date format, so you can use regular expression. As an example:

```
df[grep("05-02", df$Date),]
```

or you can transform in Date format and:

```
df$DateObs <- format(lubridate::dmy(df$Date), "%d-%m")
df[df$DateObs == "05-02"]
```

Answer (score 0):

just filter with `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
df <- df %>% as.data.table() ## convert to data table
df[format(as.Date(Date, "%m-%d-%Y"), format = "%d") == "02" & ## filter day
   format(as.Date(Date, "%m-%d-%Y"), format = "%m") == "05",] ## filter month
```

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to do a lot of day-searches then I would recommend you splitting  your data into days:

```
split_days <- split(df, sub("^([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}).*", "\\1", df$Date))
```

and then subset for date you want:

```
split_days[["05-02"]]
```

this way all pre-processing is done only once and not every time you search for different day.

**update**

idea: nested lists. First list is based on month, second list is based on days.

```
split_data <- split(df, sub("^0", "", sub("^([0-9]{2}).*", "\\1", df$Date)))  
split_data <- lapply(split_data, function(x) split(x, sub("^0", "", sub("^[0-9]{2}-([0-9]{2}).*", "\\1", x$Date))))

day <- 6
month <- 7

split_data[[as.character(month)]][[as.character(day)]]
```

if there is no match `NULL` is returned.

If you don't want to have nested list you can keep it as `data.frame`:

```
 split_data <- df %>%
      separate(Date, into = c("month", "day", "year")) %>%
      mutate(across(c("month", "day"), ~as.integer(str_remove(.x, "^0")))) %>%
      group_by(month, day) %>%
      nest() %>%
      ungroup()
```

and then use `filter` to get what you want:

```
split_data %>%
  filter(day == !!day & month == !!month) %>%
  pluck("data", 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! But is there a possibility to do the subset automatic? So I do not need to write 05-02, 05-03, 05-04 etc. ?

Comment: of course it's possible to subset based on the inputs but that depends in what format the inputs are.

Comment: How would you proceed for such a solution? Would you write a loop and replace in the split_days function the date through a variable and link the variable to a vector with all dates?

Comment: I've added update where is 1 example how it can be done in base R

Comment: That's very interesting, I will try it out in a few hours and let you know if it works! Thank you for your time and idea!

Comment: Hi det, unfortunately it doesn't seem to work properly, I've got for every month and day NULL. I think in the second split_data code lines is something wrong, but I don't get it what it is. But thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more possibility using either `stringr` or `stringi` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
#library(stringi)
df %>% 
    mutate(helper = str_extract(Date, "^.{5}")) %>% 
    # mutate(helper = stri_sub(Date, 1, 5)) %>% # with stringi package
    group_by (helper) %>% 
    filter(n() > 1) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    select(-helper)
```

Output:

```
 Date       Name     
  <chr>      <chr>    
1 05-02-2010 Alexander
2 05-02-2011 Alexander
3 05-02-2018 Chris
```